# Match unix shell promp to that of vagrant

Tags: unix, git

Not sure what it's called but in vagrant when logged in as the `vagrant` user I get a pretty line before I run commands like so:

[image]

It even says what branch i'm on in git. What is this line called and how do I get this to work on other servers such as droplets on digitalocean?

My vagrant box is running debian and my production server runs on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: It's called a prompt ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found out that it was called a prompt I was able to do some research and figured out how to get it done.

But I also found something even better:
https://github.com/nimiq/promptastic